# How to recover data from MySql Data files?

Tags: mysql

One of my servers' OS crashed yesterday. It was Win 2008.The server developed an HDD fault and did not boot.

My host provider (Turnkey) has mounted the HDD on a Rescue system and given me access to the HDD through SSH. I have been able to download the Mysql data folder and all the MYD, MYI, FRM files. (MyIsam db?).

I tried changing my local computer's data folder to the backup data folder but MySql didn't run with this data folder. At my other server the db showed up but it was empty!

I believe this could be happening due to version differences in the MySql files.

Is there any way I can recover this data? A tool maybe, or a way?

Also

- How can I find the version of mysql from the data files or the bin folder.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Impossible to answer. "MySql didn't run with this data folder" - were there any error messages? Any log lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Innodb, you need the innodb data files aswell. default names are ibdata0 and ibdata1, plus log files for it.
Did you check the logs of mysql? It would refuse to start if there is incorrect permissions or ownership for example. You should start by looking at the error messages there.